# Adjust div height based on its content

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, megamenu

I'm working on building mega menu. I have trouble when arrange div.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Mega Menu Layout Test</title>
  <style>
  h1
  {
      margin:0px;
      font-size:16px;
  }

  .wrapper
  {
      position:absolute;
      width:400px;
      background:#CCC;
  }

  .category
  {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:180px;
  }

  .subcategory
  {

  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper" >
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 3</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 4</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Consectetuer</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Adipiscing Elit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 5</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 6</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Phasellus Congue</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Fringilla Accumsan</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Praesent aliquam</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Suspendisse non purus</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 7</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Consectetuer</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Adipiscing Elit</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="category">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 8</h1>
        <div>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Consectetuer</a>
            <a href="#" style="display:block;">Adipiscing Elit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Produces **output** like this:

[image: Output]

This menu create dynamically so im difficult to set fixed height each `div`

<del>Is better way</del> How to remove empty space between  **Lorem Ipsum 3** and **Lorem Ipsum 5**; **Lorem Ipsum 5** and **Lorem Ipsum 7** ?

Comment: If you're down with using some jQuery, check out jQuery Masonry - it's great for this type of thing: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Zulkhaery--If you solved it you should post your code as a solution and then "accept" it as an answer so that this question does not remain "unanswered."

Comment: @Scott: i can't anwer after 8 hours "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."

Comment: That's fine (I forgot about that). Just try to remember and come back after 8 hours and post the corrected code in an answer and accept it so that the question does get officially answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question:

(1) Hard way: use a [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

(2) Simple way: Add new div for each colum, here the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Mega Menu Layout</title>
  <style>
  h1
  {
      margin:0px;
      font-size:16px;
  }

  .wrapper
  {
      position:absolute;
      width:400px;
      background:#CCC;
  }

  .category
  {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:90%;
  }

  .col
  {
      float:left;
      width:45%
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper" >
        <div class="col">
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 1</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 2</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum 3</h1>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category">

                    <div>
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum 4</h1>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Consectetuer</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Adipiscing Elit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum 5</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum 6</h1>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Phasellus Congue</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Fringilla Accumsan</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Praesent aliquam</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Suspendisse non purus</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum 7</h1>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Consectetuer</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Adipiscing Elit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category">
                    <div>
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum 8</h1>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Dolor Sit Amet</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Consectetuer</a>
                        <a href="#" style="display:block;">Adipiscing Elit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the spaces, yes. The other way, you'll need some wrapping div's for each 'row' you have.